# Delay loading json data from local file into React JS

Tags: reactjs

I Map the Json Data in my Component `Demo.js`, I want to delay few seconds to display the data in my component. is there any way to do this? i read about setTimeout, but dont know to use it.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Hi @ravibagul91, assume you have a h1 tag in your component, you show the value {something.title} into that h1 tag. how you delay the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `state` to show your data, and `componentDidMount` is best place to write `setTimeout`,

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state={show:false}
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({show:true})
    },2000)
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      { this.state.show && <h1>Hello</h1>}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(() => { console.log("im delayed"); }, 5000); // delayed by 5sec
```

Comment: Hi @mialnika, i want to delay the process of showing a data from JSON to the h1 tag in my component. how to o it, a simple illustration will be appreciated. thanks.